# What's the probability of an event occurs N times?

Tags: probability

There's an event A which if happens N times another event B has the probability of p to happen along with the event A.

For illustration, think of a circuit that will get current N times. The current might get to the other end or it might not. And the probability of the current NOT getting to the other end is p(so the probability of success is 1 - p).

What's the probability of B happening given that A happened N times?

Comment: You might also try asking statistics and probability questions on. Http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at it this other way: what is the probability that B never happens? $(1-p) \times \dots \times (1-p) = (1-p)^N$, therefore the probability that B happens at least once is
$$
1 - (1-p)^N.
$$
*Quick sanity check:* if $p > 0$, this probability tends to $1$ as $N$ tends to $+\infty$.

Comment: So, I have p = 0.5%. Does it mean if I try event A more and more times, event B will happen fewer and fewer times?

Comment: No, more and more.

Comment: It still doesn't look right. Let's assume I have N = 1 and p = 0.005. So, the probability of A occurring without B occurring at the same time is 0.995, right? Now if I try it again, I have 1 - 0.005^2. Now the probability of A happening without B happening is 0.999975. As you said, it tends to 1. But the chances of B happening at least once on those 2 trials is getting lower and lower. Why?

Comment: @PatrickBassut: you're right. I had taken $p$ to be the probability that $B$ does not happen when $A$ happens. I got confused because of you circuit thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear and I can see 2 interpretations:

1. Event $A$ *definitely* ($P(A_i)=1$) occurs $N$ times and $B$ occurs with $P(B)=1-p$ each time.
2. Event $A_i$ occurs with a certain probability ($P(A)=a$), if $A$ occurs $N$ times then on that occasion then event $B$ occurs with $P(B)=1-p$ once.

### Option 1

This is trivial, the probability of $B$ not occurring at all in $N$ opportunities is $p^N$. So the probability that $B$ occurs *at least once* is $1-p^N$.

### Option 2

If there is no limit on the number of opportunities for $A$ and $a>0$ and $p>0$, then $B$ will occur eventually.

You will need to clarify the question to get a more meningful answer for this option.

Comment: It's the option 1. See my comment on Siméon's answer